# Check if path exists from object in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am creating a class to render lists in active admin and I would like to do like this, given any object:

class ListGenerator
    def initialize(array_of_objects)
      @objects = array_of_objects
      generate_list
    end

```
def generate_list
  ul do
    @objects.each do |object|
      if has_show_path_for(object)
        li link_to object.name, polymorphic_path([:admin, object]
      else
        li object.name
      end
    end          
  end
end
```

This is just a sample code to explain the idea. How do I create `has_show_path_for` the method? When using `polymorphic_path` and the path exists, it returns the path. But in case it does not exist, it returns a nomethod error.

Any ideas on how to check if a path exists dynamically like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are url helpers to determine if a path is actually defined

```
if Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.method_defined?(:my_path)
```

However, this may be problematic since you seem to be checking polymorphic paths. Using a simple begin/rescue would work out well here.

```
def generate_list
    ul do
       @objects.each do |object|
           begin
               li link_to object.name, polymorphic_path([:admin, object])
           rescue NoMethodError
               li object.name
           end
    end          
end
```

or, an even shorter version...

```
def generate_list
    ul do
       @objects.each do |object|
           li link_to(object.name, polymorphic_path([:admin, object])) rescue object.name
    end          
end
```

Comment: You might want to check the syntax of your sample code. They're not syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the polymorphic_path in a `begin/rescue` block. If you reach the `rescue` portion, you know there is no such path. Thus:

```
def generate_list
    ul do
       @objects.each do |object|
           begin
               p = polymorphic_path([:admin, object])
               li link_to object.name, p
           rescue NoMethodError
               li object.name
           end
        end
    end          
end
```

Comment: Added missing 'end' stmt.